# Customized UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, customization, uipopovercontroller

How can you create a `UIPopOverController` that looks like this:

[image: iPad UIPopoverController]

Is it a custom `UIView`, or some form of `UIPopOverController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 5, it is now possible to subclass [`UIPopoverBackgroundView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverBackgroundView) and override the `popoverBackgroundViewClass` of your `UIPopoverController`. This way you can achieve what you see in the pic without having to reinvent the wheel of having to deal with a custom view and having to position it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look at this and see what i can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it is just a custom UIView, with a background image, a layer that does the shadow, and some child elements on it. It is not really that hard to make actually, so go for it.